# Recursive search using awk command

Tags: bash, recursion, awk

I have 100 log files and I want awk to search for a given pattern between a given timestamp recursively.
Log files look something like this

```
2010-03-24 07:00:01 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 GET / - 80 - 220.181.7.113 HTTP/1.1       
2010-03-24 07:00:23 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 GET
```

Code is

```
 awk -v "b=$date1" -v "e=$date2" '$1 >= b && $1 <= e' log.txt > output
 grep -i "21things" output
```

I am able to search for the pattern but for single file only. Is it possible using awk command to search recursively?

Thanks for the help..!!

Comment: use `find ... | xargs awk ...` to pass all your logs to awk

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "recursive" here? It seems like you might just mean you want to run the awk command on a bunch of files. Also, why are you using `-F ','` when there are no commas in the log files? Please edit your question to make it more clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your logs are all in the same directory, use a shell wildcard:

```
awk -v "b=$date1" -v "e=$date2" '$1 >= b && $1 <= e' *.log
```

Note that awk can do what grep does, so you don't need the temp file:

```
awk -v "b=$date1" -v "e=$date2" -v patt="21things" '
    $1 >= b && $1 <= e && tolower($0) ~ patt
' *.log
```

If you have GNU awk, use `-v IGNORECASE=1` and remove the `tolower` function.

Comment: I have always used `-v b="$date1"`, but it seems to works your way too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use find command to course through all files recursively in a directory and pass the file into awk. The following will show all the files where a match occurred. Change the <PATTERN> with required:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '/<PATTERN>/{print FILENAME; nextfile}' '{}' \;
```

The following will print out all lines matched along with  filename:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '/<PATTERN>/{print FILENAME ":\t" $0;}' '{}' \;
```